# How would I go about setting up a ProxyJump using Guacamole-JS?

Tags: guacamole, guacamole-common.js

I am creating an application where i have a web based ssh terminal that is currently connecting to a server. I have different switches that are connected to this server and I was hoping to be able to ssh into these devices directly from my site from the web terminal. How would I go about this? Is there a proxyjump set up for guacamole?

I attempted to create a new websocket right after the one used to connect to the server but it was not successful.
` const guac = new Guacamole.Client(
new Guacamole.WebSocketTunnel(baseWebSocketURL + paramsWebSocketURL)
);

```
// Add client to display div
guacamoleDisplay.appendChild(guac.getDisplay().getElement());

// Connect to the client
console.log(guac);
guac.connect();`
```